# How do I "sheetwise" save or export an Excel workbook as a PDF file?

Tags: c#, .net, excel, excel-interop, worksheet

The problem with the code I have is that either it saves all the pages in all the worksheets in the workbook or it saves only the pages in the range specified by the "from" and "to" arguments.

The excel files I am working with have 7 worksheets, and each worksheet can have any amount of pages. If I specify that I want to export "from 1 to 4", for example, then only the first 4 pages of the first worksheet would be exported as a PDF document, not all the pages of the first 4 worksheets.

Can someone tell me how to achieve what I'm trying to do? The code below is not what I want:

```
application.ActiveWorkbook.ExportAsFixedFormat(
      Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF,
      path,
      Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard,
      true,
      true,
      1,
      4,
      false,
      Missing.Value);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the answer: ActiveSheet.PageSetup.Pages.Count

Answer (score 2):

If you use `ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat` after selecting multiple sheets I think it will do what you want (as long as your print areas are set up on each of the selected sheets).

A raw recorded macro along those lines:

```
    Sheets(Array("Sheet1", "Sheet2")).Select

    ActiveSheet.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, Filename:= _
    "C:\Documents and Settings\yourusername\Desktop\Book1.pdf", _  
    Quality:=xlQualityStandard, _
    IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:= False
```

Comment: Man, you are a life saver, I was stuck by hours

Answer (score -1):

```
Public Sub Export(ParamArray ToPrint() As Variant)

'hide all sheets
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    Sheet.Hide

Next Sheet

'unhide sheets to print
For Each pageNo In ToPrint

ActiveWorkbook.Sheets(pageNo).Show

Next pageNo

'do the export
    Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat _
        Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, _
        Path, _
        Excel.XlFixedFormatQuality.xlQualityStandard, _
        True, _
        True, _
        Nothing, _
        Nothing, _
        False, _
        Missing.Value

'unhide all sheets
For Each Sheet In ActiveWorkbook.Sheets

    Sheet.Show

Next Sheet
```

End Sub

Call it by passing in a comma seperated list of sheets to export

```
Export 1, 2, 4
```

Comment: The problem with your strategy is that each time ExportAsFixedFormat() is called it overwrites the PDF file. In other words, the sheets are not appended to the PDF file; instead, a new PDF file consisting of one worksheet is created each time the loop iterates. I'm sure it's possible to find a way to merge all the resulting PDF files, but that's a bit clumsy. Can this be done using the Excel API? (I also thought of deleting the worksheets I don't want from the excel file by calling the Delete() method, but that doesn't change anything.)

Comment: Ok, i think I see what you mean.  you want to say export 1 t0 4 and it exports SHEETS 1 to 4, regardless of how many pages they have?