# Convert a list of excel sheets (sheet name list provided) into a single PDF file

Tags: c#, excel, pdf

I need to add selected set of sheets into a pdf using **Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel** library in C#. I have been searching throught he net to figure out how to this. But I haven't been able to find anything helpful. Can someone help me with this. Found following statement to convert a given sheet to a pdf. But it looks like, it cannot append list of excel sheets into one pdf when we provide sheet names.

```
xlws.ExportAsFixedFormat(Excel.XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, endPath);
```

Help please.

Comment: I think this is what you're looking for.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11835494/how-do-i-sheetwise-save-or-export-an-excel-workbook-as-a-pdf-file

Comment: You might find this useful. [stackoverflow.com/questions/35430582/how-to-convert-excel-workbook-to-pdf-without-using-excel-interop-library](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/35430582/how-to-convert-excel-workbook-to-pdf-without-using-excel-interop-library)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the Worksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat method.

Example:

```
string exportFilePath = @"C:\Desktop\Test.pdf";
activeWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, exportFilePath);
```

Or you can also use the Workbook.ExportAsFixedFormat method

```
string exportFilePath = @"C:\Desktop\Test.pdf";
activeWorksheet.ExportAsFixedFormat(XlFixedFormatType.xlTypePDF, exportFilePath);
```

References:

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.worksheet.exportasfixedformat.aspx

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.tools.excel.workbook.exportasfixedformat.aspx